# PHP split array based on search results

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which is created by a MySQL query which collects results based on a number of groups and sums. The array is below.

I'm interested in the costtotal and hitcount for each type of 'ad_type', 'click_status' and 'link_status' variation.

The possible values of the 3 types of variable are known:
i.e.

- ad_type 0 / 1
- click_status 2 / 3
- link_status 1 / 2

I would like to create a new array based on the results of each combination.

I'm guessing a search or split would do it but I'm not having much luck.

How would I go about doing this?

```
Array
(
    [0.261346210037681] => Array
        (
            [costtotal] => 0.0015
            [hitcount] => 1
            [ad_type] => 0
            [click_status] => 2
            [link_status] => 1
        )

    [0.190427019438173] => Array
        (
            [costtotal] => 0.001
            [hitcount] => 1
            [ad_type] => 0
            [click_status] => 3
            [link_status] => 1
        )

    [0.563596305962276] => Array
        (
            [costtotal] => 0.007
            [hitcount] => 5
            [ad_type] => 1
            [click_status] => 2
            [link_status] => 1
        )

    [0.893211513658251] => Array
        (
            [costtotal] => 0
            [hitcount] => 3
            [ad_type] => 1
            [click_status] => 2
            [link_status] => 2
        )

    [0.209184847035617] => Array
        (
            [costtotal] => 0.004
            [hitcount] => 2
            [ad_type] => 1
            [click_status] => 3
            [link_status] => 1
        )

    [0.73545002260753] => Array
        (
            [costtotal] => 0
            [hitcount] => 1
            [ad_type] => 1
            [click_status] => 3
            [link_status] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I fully understand what you want, then this code should satisfy you:

```
function generateClickCounterInfo() {
    return array(
        'costTotal' => 0.0,
        'hitCount' => 0
    );
}

function generateLinkStatusStructure() {
    return array(
        1 => generateClickCounterInfo(),
        2 => generateClickCounterInfo()
    );
}

function generateClickStatusStructure() {
    return array(
        2 => generateLinkStatusStructure(),
        3 => generateLinkStatusStructure()
    );
}

function generateAdTypeArrayStructure() {
    return array(
        0 => generateClickStatusStructure(),
        1 => generateClickStatusStructure()
    );
}

function getClickCounterReport(array $data) {
    $result = generateAdTypeArrayStructure();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $adType      = $value['ad_type'];
        $clickStatus = $value['click_status'];
        $linkStatus  = $value['link_status'];


        if (!isset($result[$adType])
            || !isset($result[$adType][$clickStatus])
            || !isset($result[$adType][$clickStatus][$linkStatus])) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Input data does not conform to expected format. " .
                "ad_type = {$adType}, click_status = {$clickStatus}, link_status = ${linkStatus}"
            );
        }

        $costTotal = $value['costtotal'];
        $hitCount  = $value['hitcount'];

        $result[$adType][$clickStatus][$linkStatus]['costTotal'] += $costTotal;
        $result[$adType][$clickStatus][$linkStatus]['hitCount']  += $hitCount;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And than `getClickCounterReport($data)` (where `$data` is data provided by you) will produce following array: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/607464/

P.S. Knowing disadvantages:

- No OOP (but these functions will be easy to transform to methods)
- Magick numbers (0, 1, 2, 3 etc)

Comment: that was much more than I was expecting. after a bit of head scratching I've figured out what you've done and its great. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

No array splitting is necessary. Simply create the variables that will store the totals for each of the permutation you want to measure and iterate through your array. Add to appropriate variables based upon the value you observe in ad_type, click_status, and link_status.